# refresh jquery mobile div after getting data using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery-mobile-ajax

php file:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $orgID=$row["InstancesID"];
    echo "description: " . $row["describtion"]. "<br><br>"." - Type: " . $row["type"]. "<br><br>". "-Amount: " . $row["amount"]. "<br><br>";
    echo"<input type='button'  onclick=SendID($orgID) value='updateee'/> <br><br>";
}
```

ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show").click(function(){


    $.ajax({url: "http://127.0.0.1/testupdate.php?f=ShowAllInstances",

            success: function(result){
            //alert(result);
       $("#divshow").html(result);
    }});
});
});
```

this displays the returned data in html page I want to display them in jquery mobile page.
any help please

Comment: I am confused, are you asking how to refresh your page after success? or display the returned data?

Comment: what is the " jquery mobile page"? the returned is populating #divshow as you ask it to ?